# Substituting values in an array for one cell

Tags: macos, google-sheets, formula

**The Situation**:
[1 Spreadsheet Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNx7w.png)
[2 E3 Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He9Ur.png)

I'm attempting to:

1. substitute particular symbols (see Column A - 1 Spreadsheet Overview) with another symbols (see Column B - 1 Spreadsheet Overview) for a particular cell (see E3 - 2 E3 Formula).
2. keep the formula as concise as practical for future decomposition.

The final code is being entered as a command (will improve upon this in the future) into Terminal (Mac OSX) to account for these particular symbols.

Is it possible to perform an array formula for this Google Sheets command *(without any additional code like VBA, JavaScript etc)*?

My E5 formula is:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(E15,INDEX(A3:A13,MATCH(A3:B13,A3:A13,0)),INDEX(B3:B13,MATCH(A3:B13,A3:A13,0)))
```

At this point in time, it only reacts to the first symbol: see cell A3 and B3 - `(` and `\(`

For my own personal preference, the code in E3 (all the different substitutes) is far too long and cumbersome to adapt, e.g. wanting to make an "infinity" number of symbols (Column A) and corresponding Column B symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REGEXREPLACE to the rescue:

This will create a regex of the character literals you are looking for and actually escape them.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(
  B13,
  "([\" & JOIN("([\", A3:A13) & "])", 
  "\\$1")
```